# Geotools throws "Cannot encode multilinestring (yet)" while Shape import on Linux

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I've encountered a strange platform-dependent SHP import problem.

Everything works fine on Windows, shapefiles are converted fine to database.
There is although small little warning:

> [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] WARN geotools.jdbc  - No mapping for com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.MultiLineString

Obviously SHP contains Multilinestring. So why the same code on Windows works, but on Linux we've got exception:

> UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot encode MultiLineString (yet)")

Comment: looks like this is coming from the database driver code (jdbc) - which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using 64bit oracle 11r2 enterprise edition, Linux Oracle 5 also 64bit